# Add user to Google API

Tags: google-api

In console.developers.google.com, I am trying to add permissions to a new user, with this email: xxxx@gmail.com, while my current console.developers.google.com is a google app account, let's call it yyyy@gapp.net

This is the error I got while granting xxxx@gmail.com admin/can edit/can read:

```
The non-domain account: xxxx@gmail.com can not be added to a domain project.
```

What should I do? Any setting I can tweak to solve this?

I am doing this because I want to transfer my app from yyyy@gapp.net to xxxx@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to share an app outside the domain in this way. You'll need to create a new project in the gmail.com account and switch to using it.